# String to image

Tags: java, android

I use following code for get bitmap from string but i get null bitmap. So please guide me.

```
                    byte[]  Image_getByte = Base64.decode(img);

                    ByteArrayInputStream bytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(Image_getByte);

        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(bytes);

        Bitmap bitmap=bmd.getBitmap();

        Log.v("log","Home bitmap  "+bitmap);

        i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you should use BitmapFactory.decodeStream instead of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

use **BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Image_getByte)**

here you don't need any String, after getting the byte array, just pass it in the mentioned method which returns **Bitmap**

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for `getBitmap()` says:

> *"Returns the bitmap used by this drawable to render. **May be null.**"*

Answer (score 0):

If img is base 64 String use the following source to get the bitmap from base 64 string.

```
byte[] source=img.getBytes();
byte[]  Image_getByte = Base64.decode(source);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Image_getByte, 0,Image_getByte.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This may help you

Answer (score 0):

Please consider  'ImageContents'  as String which contains image data.

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(ImageContents.getBytes());
    ImageView image = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    image.setImageBitmap(
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
    );
```

> ImageView :In Android, you can use “android.widget.ImageView” class to
>   display an image file
>
> BitmapFactory:Creates Bitmap objects from various sources, including
>   files, streams, and byte-arrays.

For more information about BitmapFactory see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)